# new monitor won't work on win3.1

Tags: windows-3.1

My old system monitor for my Windows 3.1 machine failed and the new flat screen has a sync error.

The new monitors do not support the refresh/screen size it is set to. It boots up into Windows and the monitor is blank with a sync error. Without Windows 3.1 working I don't know how to change the refresh/size to get it to work. I haven't used Win3.1 in so long that I can't remember how to fix this.

So, how do I reset the refresh rate and screen resolution it is set to, without being able to actually see anything?

Comment: What interface is the new monitor? Are we running this on a old windows 3.1 system or a modern one with something else?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to virtualize your Windows 3.1 installation through a Physical to Virtual method? Or are you running older devices that require Win 3.1?

Answer (score 2):

Run setup.exe from c:\Windows to change the current driver.  You're best bet is to switch back to the standard VGA driver to get yourself back into Windows.